# how can we access some property/attribute of particular div after getting it from e.target.parentNode

Tags: javascript

`e.target.parentNode` return this

```
    <div class="quantity">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>
        <span class="product_Count"> 4 </span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
    </div>
```

So how can we change count of "product_count" class? Remember there are multiple div same as above so how can we change count of only this div after getting it from `e.target.parentNode`?

Comment: `.querySelector(".product_Count")`

Comment: no there are multiple quannity which has similar class. so i want to update that particular count only. thats why i have defined e.target.parentNode.

Comment: remember .querySelector(".product_Count") always gets 1st record with that class

Comment: Yes, but there is only one that is inside that `e.target.parentNode` you have selected.

Answer (score 2):

`e.target.parentNode` will return the parent of the target element which triggered the event. On the returned parent element, you can use any of the following functions to select the `.product_Count` element

- `.querySelector('.product_Count');`
- `.getElementsByClassName('product_Count')[0];`

Above functions will select the `.product_Count` element within the element returned by `e.target.parentNode`. To update the count, use any of the following:

- `.innerHTML`
- `.textContent`

As mentioned in your question that there are multiple `div` elements with `.quantity` class, so instead of adding event listeners on individual `.glyphicon` elements, you could take advantage of [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture) and add a single click event listener on the parent element of all the `.quantity` elements.

See the snippet below which shows how you could increment/decrement count when there are more than one `.quantity` elements

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const target = e.target;

  if (target.matches('.glyphicon')) {
    const parentEl = target.closest('.quantity');
    const countEl = parentEl.querySelector('.product_Count');
    let count = Number(countEl.textContent);

    if (target.matches('.minus')) {
      count -= 1;
    } else {
      count += 1;
    }

    countEl.textContent = count;
  }
});
```

```css
.glyphicon {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="quantity">
    <span class="glyphicon minus">-</span>
    <span class="product_Count"> 4 </span>
    <span class="glyphicon plus">+</span>
  </div>

  <br/>

  <div class="quantity">
    <span class="glyphicon minus">-</span>
    <span class="product_Count"> 2 </span>
    <span class="glyphicon plus">+</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

If you don't want the count to be negative, make sure that you only update the count if after decrement, its value is not less than zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to increment the product count when someone clicks the plus sign? You should use `e.target.nextElementSibling` and `e.target.previousElementSibling` to select the product count element. Then, you can update its text using `elem.text = 'foobar'.

So if they click the minus sign,

```js
function onMinusClicked(event){
  let num = parseInt(event.target.nextElementSibling.text);
  event.target.nextElementSibling.text = num - 1;
}
```

and for the plus sign,

```js
function onPlusClicked(event){
  let num = parseInt(event.target.previousElementSibling.text);
  event.target.previousElementSibling.text = num + 1;
}
```

This solution works even if there are multiple divs with class `quantity`.

Comment: It's generally not advised to over-rely on `next/previous` siblings, as even a tiny change to the underlying HTML can break them. Classes are preferred as they are less prone to being changed without consideration of consequences. In fact personally I'd advice `.closest(".quantity")` over `parentNode` for the same reason.